# Linq to XML Add element to specific sub tree

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My XML:

```
<Bank>
 <Customer id="0">
  <Accounts>
   <Account id="0" />
   <Account id="1" />                      
  </Accounts>
 </Customer>
 <Customer id="1">
  <Accounts>
   <Account id="0" />                    
   </Accounts>
 </Customer>
 <Customer id="2">
  <Accounts>
   <Account id="0" />                    
  </Accounts>
 </Customer>
</Bank>
```

I want to add new Account element to lets say Customer with id 2. I know how to add the line what I dont know how do I specify the customer (where do I write the Customer's ID ?)

My LINQ to XML code:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("database.xml");
document.Element("Bank").Element("Customer").Element("Accounts").Add
     (
         new XElement
             (
                 "Account", new XAttribute("id", "variable")
             )
      );
document.Save("database.xml");
```

Thanks for the help. XML is not my good friend :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are almost there, your code will be default add the element to the first `Customer`. You need to search for the attribute `id` in collection of Customers whose value is 2 -

```
document.Element("Bank").Elements("Customer")
        .First(c => (int)c.Attribute("id") == 2).Element("Accounts").Add
                 (
                     new XElement
                         (
                             "Account", new XAttribute("id", "variable")
                         )
                  );
```

Comment: this one works perfectly thanks a lot. Now I know how to do that

Comment: Thanks, Rohit. I have been trying to access multiple grand grand child node and this helped me after trying most of the failed solutions.

Answer (score 3):

> I know how to add the line what I dont know how do I specify the customer (where do I write the Customer's ID ?)

You need to find the `Customer` element with the right ID first. For example:

```
var customer = document.Root
                       .Elements("Customer")
                       .Single(x => (int) x.Attribute("id") == id);
customer.Element("Accounts").Add(new XElement("Account",
                                              new XAttribute("id", "variable")));
```

Note that this will fail on the `Single` call if there isn't exactly one `Customer` element with the right ID. If you want to create a *new* customer, you'll need to do a bit more work - but presumably that would be in a different call anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cust = xDoc.Descendants("Customer")
               .First(c => c.Attribute("id").Value == "2");
cust.Element("Accounts").Add(new XElement("Account", new XAttribute("id","3") ));
```