# Reading large XML files with C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I would like to know how can I read a XML file from my desktop and put it into a string?

Here is my XML:

```
<smallusers>
    <user id="1">
        <name>John</name>
        <motto>I am john, who are you?</motto>
    </user>
    <user id="2">
        <name>Peter</name>
        <motto>Hello everyone!</motto>
    </user>
</smallusers>
<bigusers>
    <user id="3">
        <name>Barry</name>
        <motto>Earth is awesome</motto>
    </user>
</bigusers>
```

I want to store each user, but still detect if their small or big, is there a way to do this?

Before you downrate this, you might want to check google because I did research, but found nothing.

Comment: I don't know what that is?

Comment: Like I have explained, I can't find any information on doing this with multiple roots.

Comment: What do you mean with " read an xml file from my desktop and put it into a string"???

Comment: A string list maybe? I just want to store it somewhere.

Comment: Like a list for big users, and a list for small users, and add <user> in the lists

Comment: there's `LINQ to XML`. bunch of examples can be found. [reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml) example. [adding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333712/linq-to-xml-add-element-to-specific-sub-tree) example.

Comment: So you need to deserialize it. Is it correct?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485116/how-to-deserialize-xml-using-linq

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Error: There are multiple root elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042902/xml-error-there-are-multiple-root-elements) - just because you mentioned that "I can't find any information on doing this with multiple roots."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> "Before you downrate this, you might want to check google because I
>   did research, but found nothing"

You found nothing because you don't know what you are searching for, also your XML is invalid, you need to enclose it in a `rootElement`. Then the first thing you need to do is read this file from the desktop if it exists.

You can check the size if you wish at that time and determine if this is "too large" even though it doesn't really matter. I highly doubt your XML file will be 5+ GB in size. If it is then you need an alternative, no single object in a .Net program may be over 2GB, the best you could do is 1,073,741,823 on a 64bit machine.

**For very large XML files, anything above 1.0 GB, combine XmlReader and LINQ as stated by Jon Skeet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp):**

> If your document is particularly huge, you can combine XmlReader and
>   LINQ to XML by creating an XElement from an XmlReader for each of your
>   "outer" elements in a streaming manner: this lets you do most of the
>   conversion work in LINQ to XML, but still only need a small portion of
>   the document in memory at any one time.

**For small XML files, anything 1.0 GB or lower stick to the DOM as shown below.**

With that said, what you need is to learn what `Serialization` and `Deserialization` mean.

`Serialize` convert an object instance to an XML document.

`Deserialize` convert an XML document into an object instance.

Instead of XML you can also use JSON, binary, etc.

In your case this is what can be done to `Deserialize` this `XML` document back into an Object in order for you to use in your code.

First fix up the XML and give it a Root.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataRoot>
    <smallusers>
        <user id="1">
            <name>John</name>
            <motto>I am john, who are you?</motto>
        </user>
        <user id="2">
            <name>Peter</name>
            <motto>Hello everyone!</motto>
        </user>
    </smallusers>
    <bigusers>
        <user id="3">
            <name>Barry</name>
            <motto>Earth is awesome</motto>
        </user>
    </bigusers>
</DataRoot>
```

Then create the root class in C#, you may generate this directly in Visual Studio 2012+ by copying your XML and going to `Edit` - `Paste Special`, but I like to use: [XML to C# Class Generator](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

Here is what your code would look like after you generate the C# Root Class for your XML, hope it helps you understand it better.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "user")]
        public class User
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "motto")]
            public string Motto { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "smallusers")]
        public class Smallusers
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "user")]
            public List<User> User { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "bigusers")]
        public class Bigusers
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "user")]
            public User User { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DataRoot")]
        public class DataRoot
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "smallusers")]
            public Smallusers Smallusers { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "bigusers")]
            public Bigusers Bigusers { get; set; }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string testXMLData = @"<DataRoot><smallusers><user id=""1""><name>John</name><motto>I am john, who are you?</motto></user><user id=""2""><name>Peter</name><motto>Hello everyone!</motto></user></smallusers><bigusers><user id=""3""><name>Barry</name><motto>Earth is awesome</motto></user></bigusers></DataRoot>";

            var fileXmlData = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\XMLFile.xml");
            var deserializedObject = DeserializeFromXML(fileXmlData);
            var serializedToXML = SerializeToXml(deserializedObject);

            //I want to store each user, but still detect if their small or big, is there a way to do this?
            foreach (var smallUser in deserializedObject.Smallusers.User)
            {
              //Iterating your collection of Small users? 
              //Do what you need here with `smalluser`.
              var name = smallUser.Name; //Example...
            }


            Console.WriteLine(serializedToXML);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string SerializeToXml(DataRoot DataObject)
        {
            var xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataRoot));

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
                {
                    xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, DataObject);
                    var data = sw.ToString();
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Close();
                    sw.Flush();
                    sw.Close();
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }

        public static DataRoot DeserializeFromXML(string xml)
        {
            var xsExpirations = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataRoot));
            DataRoot rootDataObj = null;
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                rootDataObj = (DataRoot)xsExpirations.Deserialize(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }
            return rootDataObj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are scenarios, where you have to read large xml files. Consider analysing communication culture in different fields of technology. You can [download dumps from relevant stackexchange sites](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and extract posts and comments. Naively sucking all in does not work (14GiB Comments.xml on stackoverflow). Then go ahead google, find relevant Question like **Reading large XML files with C#** and get disappointed. Your _I highly doubt your xml file will be 5+ GB in size._ is a punch in the face. It simply does not apply to *Reading large XML files with C#*

Comment: @mbx Fair enough, I went ahead and updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: thx :-) here, [have a presentation about **Exploring StackOverflow data**](https://youtu.be/VU1ObHfDNPQ)