# LINQ: add child element inside an element

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I know there have been many related questions like this before
for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333712/linq-to-xml-add-element-to-specific-sub-tree)

But I am not being able to solve one simple problem.

Here is an example

```
        int id = 1;
        var doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0","utf-8","yes"));
        doc.Add(new XElement("root", new XAttribute("Version", "1.1.0")));
        doc.Root.Add(new XElement("subroot", new XAttribute("ID", id)));
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

This yeilds following result

[image]

All good till here.
Now I want to add new child element inside subroot.

This is what I have tried

```
        doc.Element("subroot").Add(new XElement("InsideSubroot"), new XAttribute("name","xyz"));
```

This however throws exception saying Object reference not set to instance of an object.

Another try was

```
    doc.Elements("subroot").Single(x=> (int) x.Attribute("ID") == id).Add(new XElement("InsideSubroot"), new XAttribute("name","xyz"));
```

This says cannot find matching element.

Could someone explain what is happening and why I am getting these errors.
And how to add child element. In my case inside subroot element

Comment: what about the root? `doc.Root.Elements(...)`?

Comment: Does this works? Document.Root.Element("subroot").Add(new XElement("InsideSubroot"), new XAttribute("name","xyz"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subroot` is not a direct child of the document. You should use `Descendents` instead:

```
doc
    .Descendants("subroot")
    .Single(x => (int)x.Attribute("ID") == id)
    .Add(new XElement("InsideSubroot"), new XAttribute("name","xyz"));
```